# How to change change value of button

Tags: knockout.js

I am new in MVC and not able to replicate this problem. I am trying to change the text of button.

Fiddle [`here`](http://jsfiddle.net/d4kkg/2/)

View

```
 <input type="button" data-bind="click: $root.save" value="Save" />
```

ViewModal

```
function AppViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.save = function () {
alert('me');
//change button text here       
    }
}

  ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

Comment: You haven't tried anything and it doesn't appear you have even looked at the docs nor gone through the tutorials on their site.  Changing the `text` attribute is the most basic thing you can do...

Comment: You should also supply a direct question to give the readers a focus.

Comment: @Anton: I added both part now it's fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to go through the docs but given your question is so simple hopefully providing this will steer you towards trying to learn knockout instead of asking for others to write code for you -

http://jsfiddle.net/d4kkg/4/

```
<input data-bind="attr: { 'value': someText }" type="button"/>
```

Comment: If i want to change text on load not on click then hoe it work?

Comment: Just go read the docs you asked a poor question and now you are going to keep changing the question to try to get me to teach you knockout - just go read the docs and use the tutorials they provide.

Comment: I'm new in this technology.. I dn't know how things work in this, so i asked this question.

Comment: The best way to learn it is to follow their tutorials.

Comment: Thanks, next time i remember it